# Can we integrate to IdServer3 without using an OWIN client?

Tags: wif, identityserver3

I have an existing MVC .net application that uses its own forms based authentication. Currently we only have forms authentication enabled

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

We are extending this application to a new subset of users. They are already on my idserver3 and they are using few other applications through idserver3.

Now i have to also support forms authentication and Authentication using idserver3. At the time of application start up, it could be determined if that installation requires Forms or Idserver authentication.

Is it possible to add Openid connect authentication with Idserver3 without using OWIN pipeline in my .net MVC client applications?

Comment: No. Not without forking the project and unpicking OWIN/Katana and making the required classes public

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Identity Server client interface is based on OWIN, so I don't think you can have both.  I recently had to convert an MVC app with Forms Authentication to Identity Server and I had to remove the forms authentication to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using WIF? You've tagged it with WIF. WIF doesn't implement OIDC.

idsrv3 uses OWIN on its side but OIDC / OAuth is all based on REST so you can implement the calls natively on your side if you want.

However, it makes life a lot easier if you use the OWIN stack.

Comment: Why the markdown? The question specifically states "without using OWIN pipeline in my .net MVC client applications?" The question is about the client side NOT idsrv3.

Comment: Something like this on the side works. https://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/10/writing-an-openid-connect-web-client-from-scratch/